# Combine two datasets, based on POSIXct values

Tags: r, join, dplyr, data.table, posixct

I am struggling with combining two datasets with each other.

> Dataset1 is containing a "before time" and a "after time", and a "channel".
>
> Dataset2 is containing just one "time" and a "channel" column as well.

I want to add an binary column (Yes/No) to Dataset1, with this logic: 
If there is a row in Dataset2, where the channel == channel, and Time is within the "before" and "after" time, I want to have "YES". Else "NO".

**Data1**

```
ID   Channel   before_time   after_time 
1       A1  2019-09-02 20:13:00 2019-09-02 20:33:00
2       B1  2019-09-02 20:03:00 2019-09-02 20:23:00
3       C1  2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00
4       D1  2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00
```

**Data2**

```
ID_B     Channel_B    Time_B
Hallo       A1        2019-09-02 20:23:00
Hi          B2        2019-09-02 20:05:00
Hoi         C1        2019-09-02 22:23:00
```

**Desired Output**

```
ID   Channel   before_time   after_time                     Available
1       A1  2019-09-02 20:13:00 2019-09-02 20:33:00         Yes  # Channel == Channel, Time between before & after
2       B1  2019-09-02 20:03:00 2019-09-02 20:23:00          No  # Channel != Channel
3       C1  2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00          No  # Time is not between before & after
4       D1  2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00          No  # There is no matching data where channel is D1
```

**Desired Output 2 (comments Solutions)**

Adding extra columns from the second data set (Data2).

```
ID   Channel   before_time   after_time                     Available   ID_B     
1       A1  2019-09-02 20:13:00 2019-09-02 20:33:00          Yes        Hallo       
2       B1  2019-09-02 20:03:00 2019-09-02 20:23:00          No         x 
3       C1  2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00          No         x
4       D1  2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00          No         x
```

**Reproducible example (the data):**

```
ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "4")
channel <- c("A1", "B1", "C1", "D1)
#startdate <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-02 20:23:00", "2019-09-02 20:13:00", "2019-09-02 20:33:00", "2019-09-02 20:33:00"))
before_time <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-02 20:13:00", "2019-09-02 20:03:00", "2019-09-02 20:23:00", "2019-09-02 20:23:00"))
after_time  <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-02 20:33:00", "2019-09-02 20:23:00", "2019-09-02 20:43:00","2019-09-02 20:43:00"))
data1 <- data.frame(ID, channel,   before_time, after_time)
View(data1)


ID_B <- c("Hallo", "Hi", "Hoi")
channel_B <- c("A1", "B2", "C1")
Time_B <- as.POSIXct(c("2019-09-02 20:23:00", "2019-09-02 20:05:00", "2019-09-02 22:23:00"))
data2 <- data.frame(ID_B, channel_B, Time_B)
View(data2)
```

Comment: Have your real data equal number of rows?

Comment: Look into non-equi joins, update joins, this can be done with `data.table`. Joining in `dplyr` is not (yet) so advanced, but if you do a full join and then compare the dates should also work.

Comment: @ArmandoGonzálezDíaz the real data does not have equal number of rows. I changed my example.

Comment: @arg0naut91 appreciate the advice. Has added the 'data.table' tag and will look into full-joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by arg0naut91, here is non-equi join in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
setDT(data2)
data1[, c("Available", "ID_B") :=
        data2[.SD, on=.(channel_B=channel, Time_B>=before_time, Time_B<=after_time), 
            by=.EACHI, .(.N > 0, ID_B)][, (1L:3L) := NULL]
    ]
```

output:

```
   ID channel         before_time          after_time Available  ID_B
1:  1      A1 2019-09-02 20:13:00 2019-09-02 20:33:00      TRUE Hallo
2:  2      B1 2019-09-02 20:03:00 2019-09-02 20:23:00     FALSE  <NA>
3:  3      C1 2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00     FALSE  <NA>
4:  4      D1 2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00     FALSE  <NA>
```

Comment: Great, @chinsoon12. However, if I run your example I receive an error (or is it me?): Error in set(i, j = lc, value = newfactor) : 
  .SD is locked. Updating .SD by reference using := or set are reserved for future use. Use := in j directly. Or use copy(.SD) as a (slow) last resort, until shallow() is exported.

Comment: can you use an updated version of data.table? and if you cannot upgrade your version, you will need to replace `.SD` with `copy(.SD)` or `data1`

Comment: Your solution works. Quick question, since i have some trouble with the DT syntax: would it be possible to add columns from data2 if there is a TRUE (match)? 

For example, adding 'ID_B' to the output file?

Comment: Can you show some example data? Not in front of computer now

Comment: Sure, I updated the question (data examples are still there). Does that make sense for you? Thanks!

Comment: @Roverflow, i have updated the code to add the new column

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work:

```
df<-(cbind(data1,data2)

df<-df%>%mutate(ID=as.integer(ID),
        channel=as.character(channel),
        ID_B=as.character(ID_B),
        channel_B=as.character(channel_B))

df%>%
  mutate(available= ifelse(channel==channel_B & Time_B >= before_time & Time_B <= after_time, "yes","no"))%>%
  select(-ID_B,Time_B,-channel_B)


 # A tibble: 3 x 5
 ID channel before_time         after_time          available
 <int> <chr>   <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>    
 1     1 A1      2019-09-02 20:13:00 2019-09-02 20:33:00 yes      
 2     2 B1      2019-09-02 20:03:00 2019-09-02 20:23:00 no       
 3     3 C1      2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00 no
```

Comment: I tried this solution. However, it is leading to: Error: Expecting a single value: [extent=3].

Comment: Could you please upload the solution including the data examples that are posted above? I am still receiving errors (although I adjusted the names of the data1 to df etc.). Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `df=cbind(data1,data2)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution, using `merge` + `ifelse`, i.e.,

```
dfout <- subset(within(merge(data1,data2[-1],by.x = "channel",by.y = "channel_B",all.x = T), 
                       Available <- ifelse(!is.na(Time_B)& Time_B>=before_time & Time_B<=after_time,"Yes","No")),
                select = -Time_B)
```

such that

```
> dfout
  channel ID         before_time          after_time Available
1      A1  1 2019-09-02 20:13:00 2019-09-02 20:33:00       Yes
2      B1  2 2019-09-02 20:03:00 2019-09-02 20:23:00        No
3      C1  3 2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00        No
4      D1  4 2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00        No
```

Answer (score 1):

It may also make sense to look into `sqldf`, e.g.:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf('SELECT t1.ID, t1.channel, 
      t1.before_time, t1.after_time, 
      CASE WHEN t2.ID_B IS NULL THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END Available 
      FROM data1 t1 LEFT JOIN data2 t2 ON t1.channel = t2.channel_B
      AND t2.Time_B BETWEEN t1.before_time AND t1.after_time')
```

Output:

```
  ID channel         before_time          after_time Available
1  1      A1 2019-09-02 20:13:00 2019-09-02 20:33:00       Yes
2  2      B1 2019-09-02 20:03:00 2019-09-02 20:23:00        No
3  3      C1 2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00        No
4  4      D1 2019-09-02 20:23:00 2019-09-02 20:43:00        No
```

Here is also one way of doing this in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data1 %>%
  left_join(data2,
            by = c('channel' = 'channel_B')
            ) %>%
  mutate(
    Available = ifelse(
      !is.na(Time_B) & Time_B >= before_time & Time_B <= after_time, 'Yes', 'No')
    ) %>%
  select(-ends_with('_B'))
```

Adding additional column:

```
# sqldf

sqldf('SELECT t1.ID, t1.channel, 
      t1.before_time, t1.after_time, 
      CASE WHEN t2.ID_B IS NULL THEN "No" ELSE "Yes" END Available,
      CASE WHEN t2.ID_B IS NULL THEN "x" ELSE t2.ID_B END ID_B
      FROM data1 t1 LEFT JOIN data2 t2 ON t1.channel = t2.channel_B
      AND t2.Time_B BETWEEN t1.before_time AND t1.after_time')

# dplyr

data1 %>%
  left_join(data2,
            by = c('channel' = 'channel_B')
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    Available = ifelse(
      !is.na(Time_B) & Time_B >= before_time & Time_B <= after_time, 'Yes', 'No'),
    ID_B = ifelse(
      Available == 'Yes', as.character(ID_B), 'x')
  ) %>%
  select(-Time_B)
```